# About sound recording, the output file was 44bytes

Tags: audio, record

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/audio-recording-in-wav-format-in-android-programming/

I follow the above link to create a sound recorder app
but when I use same code and start recording it create a folder and file of 44 byte.(it will store empty file) don not record the voice. Do anybody know what is going wrong??? Thanks :)

Comment: A wave file header is normally 44 bytes so I would guess you've written that but never appended any audio.

Comment: You need to show us the code doing the recording.